# Help needed for Hadoop to execute sbin/start-dfs.sh without being asked root login

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I have followed some other answers but was unable to find something that works

When I do

```
sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

I get prompted for the root passwd

I set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

The following line

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

I can do ssh localhost without being prompted for a root password.

I set up the keys as follows:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Where am I going wrong?

I'm sorry I'm new to this.